# "R": put all elements of a vector into one element without "paste"

Tags: r, vector, paste

I have a vector for example `test<-c("red","blue","green")`. How can i join the elements of the vector into one so i have `test<-c("red/blue/green")`.

I know I could use `paste(test[1],test[2],test[3], sep="/")` but that's too much work because my vector has hundreds of elements!

thx for your help!

Answer (score 7):

You can use `collapse` parameter of `paste`

```
> paste(test , collapse ="/")
[1] "red/blue/green"
```